# How to answer "What makes you best fit for this role"?

Tags: interviewing, india, first-job, confidence

This happened last Monday. I was interviewing for a Financial & Risk Advisory position at one of the big 4 Accounting firms. Everything went well but I messed it up at the very last question of the final interview after almost 12 hours of process which was "what makes you the best fit for this role?"

I was under the impression that the job was boring and may be I could find a better job. But the thing is no matter what the compensation was best. I answered how my skills matches to the role but in the end I answered unconfidently saying ".....I am not sure whether I am best fit for this role, but I will give my best to learn". After which the interviewer just ended the interview.

Now I regret as I come from a third world country and from lower middle class. This was one of the worst mistake I could've made.

For future interview should I be overconfident and possibly lie when answering this question, as I am fresher I may not have full insight about the role.
Also I did my homework about the researching about the company and role it's just that I wasn't confident.

I am confused because I was later advised by one of my friends that they want the lie answers (for whatever reasons) so sound like you know stuff (especially for big companies) about the company, ask question about your workplace, show interest and at least feign your competence.

Comment: Related, and possibly a duplicate of [Responding to “Why are you the best person for this job” type questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/35507/9549)

Answer (score 6):

> For future interview should I be overconfident and possibly lie when answering this question

***Don't lie in an interview***. It will start a cycle of lies if interviewer asks follow up questions, that you will come to regret later.

> as I am fresher I may not have full insight about the role.

That should not be a problem. Freshers (i.e. fresh college grads) are not usually aware of different responsibilities of a role, or how one role differs from another.

Ask the HR what the role entails. Ask the Hiring manager (if you know which one of the interviews it is). Read from the job description, or google the general expectations.

> I was later advised by one of my friends that they want the lie answers

I'm guessing your friends are also freshers. So don't listen to wrong advise of people who are themselves inexperienced, that wouldn't add any value.

And in any case, ***Don't lie in an interview***.

> Also I did my homework about the researching about the company and role it's just that I wasn't confident.

***This lack of confidence is your real problem.*** Try to practise answering such questions in the mirror, or ask a friend to take a mock interview consisting of such questions. Lying is not a solution to building confidence.

You can try preparing list of such questions, and answers that you think best reflect your personal preferences, and then practise them before such culture fit rounds.

Answer (score 2):

That sort of question isn't uncommon for wrapping up an interview. They are asking you to sell yourself.

When you lack experience, and my read of your question is that you do, your best selling point is your willingness to learn and whatever academic or extra-curricular accomplishments you have which demonstrate that.

Before I go any further, let me just say that you should **never** lie in an interview. Experienced interviewers can spot a lie very easily because usually an exaggeration is something interesting enough (no one lies about boring things) to pursue further.

What you want to look for is things you've done which show how willing and able you are to learn new things, above and beyond class work. Perhaps you did a special project, or you were part of a group at University where you did something extra-ordinary outside of class. Rather than "I'm willing to learn" you would say "My senior project covered the financial relationship between geographically diverse groups of snail farmers. I was unfamiliar with snail farming, so I studied the role of gastropod breeding in the creation of a viable snail-based economy. I will looking to learning more about your business if I'm selected for the role."

I don't know that anyone farms snails.

That is what you're looking for -- an outstanding example of how you learned new things.

Saying you don't know if you're the best fit very likely didn't hurt you. Humility is a good thing, especially with an early career candidate. You just need to find a way to back up your willingness and ability to *become* the best candidate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you responded:

> **I am not sure whether I am best fit for this role**, but I will give my best to learn

Depending on the interviewer this response might sounded something like "I am not sure if this role fits my interests". B/c this question is more to figure out not only find out what skills you can bring to the table and they missed on the interview but to probe your interest in the role. And from your own post this seems to worked perfect:

> I was under the impression that the job was boring and may be I could find a better job.

If you wanted that offer what you should've done is to highlight the skills from the job description and you already have and express that you are willing to learn new skills to perfect the role you are interviewing for. If you are part of some meetups, user groups or educating yourself on the topics that are relevant to the position you should bring it up (this would indicate that you are interested in the stuff more then a 8-5; if not you can skip it). Keep in mind that at this point you are selling yourself but **do not lie**. If you lie that would come up pretty fast (in one of the places I worked we caught applicant lying in front of the whole team, however our boss still hired that person but imagine how we perceived that person). However keep in mind that if you didn't like the job during the interview it might be a best to pull away from the job.